# How to specify batch size for Sagemaker batch Transform

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I need to run a text classifier on large (10k+) datasets of small text phrases using AWS Sagemaker Batch Transforms. My test file contains ~25k examples and is about 2.5MB is size.

I'm using the pytorch interface container, i.e. `pytorch-inference:1.13.1-cpu-py39` with a custom `inference.py`

Most of the time it works, but sometimes I see 507 errors in the logs (worker died). Looking closer they appear to be the result of out-of-memory due to huge batch sizes - sagemaker batch transform is sometimes passing 10k+ examples per batch.

I added logging to confirm this, oddly I have a mix of 1000 row batches and 10k, i.e.

```
2023-03-22T13:21:22.405+11:00   2023-03-22T02:21:22,342 [INFO ] W-9002-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Received batch of 1000
2023-03-22T13:21:25.406+11:00   2023-03-22T02:21:25,020 [INFO ] W-9002-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Received batch of 1000
2023-03-22T13:21:27.407+11:00   2023-03-22T02:21:26,796 [INFO ] W-9003-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Received batch of 1000
2023-03-22T13:21:34.411+11:00   2023-03-22T02:21:33,496 [INFO ] W-9002-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Received batch of 1000
2023-03-22T13:21:35.412+11:00   2023-03-22T02:21:35,112 [INFO ] W-9003-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Received batch of 1000
**2023-03-22T13:21:35.412+11:00 2023-03-22T02:21:35,226 [INFO ] W-9002-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Received batch of 10205**
2023-03-22T13:21:38.414+11:00   2023-03-22T02:21:37,949 [INFO ] W-9003-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Received batch of 1000
2023-03-22T13:21:40.415+11:00   2023-03-22T02:21:40,020 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Received batch of 1000
2023-03-22T13:21:41.416+11:00   2023-03-22T02:21:41,105 [INFO ] W-9003-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Received batch of 1000
2023-03-22T13:21:42.416+11:00   2023-03-22T02:21:41,994 [INFO ] W-9001-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Received batch of 1000
2023-03-22T13:21:43.417+11:00   2023-03-22T02:21:42,605 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Received batch of 1000
2023-03-22T13:21:44.417+11:00   2023-03-22T02:21:43,851 [INFO ] W-9003-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Received batch of 1000
2023-03-22T13:21:45.418+11:00   2023-03-22T02:21:44,730 [INFO ] W-9001-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Received batch of 1000
2023-03-22T13:21:45.418+11:00   2023-03-22T02:21:45,289 [INFO ] W-9000-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Received batch of 1000
**2023-03-22T13:21:53.421+11:00 2023-03-22T02:21:52,930 [INFO ] W-9003-model_1.0-stdout MODEL_LOG - Received batch of 10205**
```

How can I control this? I'm using `create_transform_job` with the request below. From my research `MaxConcurrentTransforms` controls the number of workers (I set it to the number of vCPUs) but the only parameter I can find that (indirectly) controls the batch size is `MaxPayloadInMB`, and that is an integer - ie. the smallest I can set it is 1MB which results in a batch_size of ~10k (and it depends on the content-type)! I need to be able to set it much lower - I have no idea how this could work on a GPU instance - its hardly what I'd call a mini-batch?

I'm aware of parameters that perform auto-batching when using realtime-inference. I've not (deliberately) enabled that.

I'd also like to understand why I get 2 batches of 10205 and 13 of 1000?

```py
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_CreateTransformJob.html
request = {
    "ModelClientConfig": {
        "InvocationsTimeoutInSeconds": 60, # timeout per minibatch  (raises 507 error if exceeded)
        "InvocationsMaxRetries": 2,        # minibatch retries
    },
    "TransformJobName": job_name,
    "ModelName": model_name,
    "MaxConcurrentTransforms": max_concurrent_transforms, 
    "MaxPayloadInMB": max_payload,
    "BatchStrategy": "MultiRecord",
    "TransformOutput": {
        "S3OutputPath": batch_output,
        "AssembleWith": "Line",
        "Accept": "application/jsonlines",
    },
    "TransformInput": {
        "DataSource": {"S3DataSource": {"S3DataType": "S3Prefix", "S3Uri": batch_input}},
        "SplitType": "Line",
        "ContentType": "application/jsonlines",
    },
    "TransformResources": {"InstanceType": instance_type, "InstanceCount": 1},
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that there are two different approaches to implementing the `inference.py` file containing the inference pipeline. Most of the examples use `input_fn`, `model_fn` and `output_fn` which are called by torchserver (ts). However ts also supports `tranform_fn` which provides more flexibility. In particular, you can generate mini-batches if the payload is larger than some pre-defined size.

I'm not sure where this is officially documented, I followed Huggingfaces documentation (https://huggingface.co/docs/sagemaker/inference) which says:

Here is an example of a custom inference module with model_fn, input_fn, predict_fn, and output_fn:

```py
def model_fn(model_dir):
    return "model"

def input_fn(data, content_type):
    return "data"

def predict_fn(data, model):
    return "output"

def output_fn(prediction, accept):
    return prediction
```

Customize your inference module with only model_fn and transform_fn:

```py
def model_fn(model_dir):
    return "loading model"

def transform_fn(model, input_data, content_type, accept):
    return f"output"
```

This enables a more flexible setup

```py
def transform_fn(model, input_data, content_type, accept):
    all_predictions = []
    for batch in generate_minibatches(input_data, batch_size=128):
        predictions, embeddings = model.predict(batch)
        all_results.extend(predictions)
    return all_predictions
```

Better still would be the ability to `yield` the intermediate results back to `torchserve` to further reduce memory but it solves my issue for now.